# NPM script needs exact file name

Tags: javascript, node.js

Normally when pointing node to a folder, if there is an `index.js` file there, we don't need to specify it.

I installed an NPM dependency that I am working on, `npm install --save-dev suman`.

Suman has an index.js file at the root of its NPM project.

In my NPM scripts for a project that *depends on suman*, I have this:

```
"scripts": {
 "test": "node node_modules/suman/index.js --rnr test" 
}
```

The above works!

But this doesn't work:

```
"scripts": {
 "test": "node node_modules/suman --rnr test" 
}
```

Why is this?

Perhaps the answer is obvious - the require function in node is capable of such behavior, but node itself is not.

Answer (score 1):

Since the library has a [`bin`](https://github.com/ORESoftware/suman/blob/master/package.json#L69) in its `package.json`, you don't need to explicitly provide the path to it. Just run `node suman --rnr test` and `npm` will take care of using the correct file.

When you install a dependency with a binary in your node project, npm creates a symlink to that file in `./node_modules/.bin` and uses those when running npm scripts.

Comment: didn't work quite yet, but working on it to see if it can be done

Comment: maybe dev dependencies don't have the same ability as regular deps

Comment: @AlexMills can you run `ls -l ./node_modules/.bin` and check whether the symlinks exist?

Comment: Dev dependencies work the same as dependencies for me.

Comment: yeah I have the .bin dir inside node_modules, and there is suman.ch and suman.cmd but "node suman" from npm scripts still doesn't reach it AFAICT. I am on Windows right now though, LOL. will try it on *nix tomorrow.

Comment: Can you try installing `suman` again? I just tested it, and works as expected for me. Also, in my `node_modules/.bin` directory, I have this - `suman -> ../suman/index.js`

Comment: thanks let me give it a shot tomorrow, thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the correct path:

```
"scripts": {
 "test": "node ./node_modules/suman --rnr test" 
}
```

Notice the `./`

### Update:

After thinking about this a bit more, It may not be this easy. But take a look at this link: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts - @elssar seems to be on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry that I can't include my thoughts simply as a comment rather than as an answer but I don't yet have enough reputation points to comment. However, perhaps the following is relevant:*

If, in your problem, the `node` command finds the appropriate `index.js` the same way as is shown [in the node documentation for modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), then the documented look-up routine will find a different `index.js` before finding the one that (I think) you want. Specifically, before trying `node_modules/suman/index.js` (which is the one you want), node will look to see if the `"main"` field in `node_modules/suman/package.json` exists. In suman, it does, and it references `lib/index.js` (i.e. `node_modules/suman/lib/index.js`) which is different than the one you want. Is that relevant?

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify my answer with more generic language...

Your original question is a valid one because, in the absence of any other complications, if `dir/index.js` exists, then both of the following

- `node dir/index.js ...`
- `node dir ...`

should refer to the same (default) file, i.e. `dir/index.js`. Thus it is reasonable to be confused when those two commands give different results. The explanation is that there IS a complication: the `dir/package.json` file effectively redirects `node dir ...` to use a non-default file. This is because the `"main"` property refers to `dir/some/other/file.js`. The rules of precedence specify that, if only a directory name is used, this other file will be used before the default. Thus, you are forced to continue to use the longer and more explicit "working" command from your question.

Comment: right, that is an accurate assessment thanks,  there are two index.js files that it could pick up..I am not sure which one is more likely but right now with just "node suman" it appears to be neither

Comment: I (sincerely) don't understand your continuing uncertainty. However, I just added a clarification to my response. Your original question essentially was "Why do these two different commands give different results?" Does my analysis answer your question?